# Question about Proof - Holomorph as Normalizer in $Sym(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, holomorph

I've adapted the following proof from Wikipedia ([here).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics)#Hol.28G.29_as_a_permutation_group)

Let $\lambda: G→Sym(G)$ be the homomorphism induced by letting $G$ act on itself by left multiplication. Now let $H$ denote the normalizer of $\lambda(G)$ in $Sym(G)$.

We know that for each $f$ in $H$ and $g$ in $G$, there is an $h$ in $G$ such that $f\circλ(g) = λ(h)\circ f$.

The following is the sentence (verbatim) that confuses me.

> If an element $f$ of $H$ fixes the identity of $G$, then for $1$ in $G$, $(f\circ λ(g))(1) = (λ(h)\circ f)(1)$, but the left hand side is $f(g)$, and the right side is $h$.

Basically, I just can't see why this is true. I'd appreciate it if anyone could spell this out. (I realize that I'm assuming this sentence is correct, but I think that it is because the rest of the article conforms to what I've seen in textbooks.)

Answer (score 1):

$f \circ \lambda(g)$ is a bijection on the set $G$, which on $x \in G$ takes value
$$
(f \circ \lambda(g)) (x) = f( g x).
$$
Similarly
$$
(\lambda(h) \circ f) (x) = \lambda(h) (f(x)) = h f(x).
$$ 
So if $f(1) = 1$, and you take $x = 1$ in the above formulas, you get indeed $f(g) = h$. Taking now an arbitrary $x$ you have
$$
f(g x) = f(g) f(x),
$$
so that $f$ is an automorphism of $G$.